# Unit Test for getting the PassthroughSubject publisher's value

Tags: swift, combine

Is there a way to get the value of a **PassthroughSubject** publisher in a Unit test?
I want to test that a function returns success and to test this one I want to see when the publisher value is **.loaded**, then is success.

```
class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject {

    var homeState = PassthroughSubject<StatePublisher, Never>()

    func load(item: HomeModel) {
        self.homeState.send(.loading)
        self.dataSource.load(item: item) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success:
                self.homeState.send(.loaded)
            case let .failure(error):
                self.homeState.send(.error(message: error.localizedDescription))
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
class HomeViewModelTests: XCTestCase {
    var sut: ViewModel!
    var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        sut = ViewModel()
    }

    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        sut = nil
        subscriptions = []
    }
        
    func testUpdateHomeSuccess() {
        let expected = StatePublisher.loaded
        var result = StatePublisher.loading
    
        sut.load(item: HomeModel.fixture())
        
        sut.homeState
            .sink(receiveValue: { state in
                result = state
            })
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    
        XCTAssert(
            result == expected,
            "Home expected to be \(expected) but was \(result)"
        )
    }
    
}
```

I tried a test like this, but sink is never called.

Comment: Combine framework is asynchronous. You must use an asynchronous test!

Answer (score 5):

Presumably, `dataSource.load` operates asynchronously. That means you need to use an `XCTestExpectation` in your test case. Also, because you're using a `PassthroughSubject` rather than a `CurrentValueSubject`, you should create your subscription **before** you start the load, to be sure you can't miss any published values.

```
let ex = XCTestExpectation()
sut.homeState
    .sink {
        if case .loaded = $0 {
            ex.fulfill()
        }
    }
    .store(in: &subscriptions)

wait(for: [ex], timeout: 10)
// Test fails if it doesn't call `ex.fulfill()` within 10 seconds.
```

Read Apple's guide to [Testing Asynchronous Operations with Expectations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/testing_asynchronous_operations_with_expectations).

Comment: Semantically, exactly what Rob said, but you will probably find the syntacic sugar of package “CombineExpectations” sweet: https://github.com/groue/CombineExpectations

Answer (score 0):

I changed my `PassthroughSubject` to `CurrentValueSubject` as then the state of the value is present also when executing the `XCTestCase`.

So this test was always failing: (the PassthroughSubject is declared in viewModel class which is tested)

```
var someValue: PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never> = .init()
func someTest() throws {
    let exp = expectation(description: "Value changed")
    
    viewModel.functionChangingTheValue()

    viewModel.someValue.sink { result in
        XCTAssertTrue(result)
        exp.fulfill()
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)

    wait(for: [exp], timeout: 0.1)
}
```

But this one is now successful

```
var someValue: CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never> = .init(false)
func someTest() throws {
    let exp = expectation(description: "Value changed")
    
    viewModel.functionChangingTheValue()

    viewModel.someValue.sink { result in
        XCTAssertTrue(result)
        exp.fulfill()
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)

    wait(for: [exp], timeout: 0.1)
}
```